# odbc [package suddenly incompatible

Tags: r, odbc

To my knowledge I didn't change any aspect of RSTUDIO (currently have 1.0.153), however after 48 hours of not touching a script I'm working on, numerous packages are now needing an install, whereas previously the require or library functions would work.

Additionally, and more troubling is that now I get an error that odbc isn't compatible with this version of R, and since that's how I'm presently connecting to the Azure SQL where my tables live, the entire script is non-functional.

I feel as though there's something obvious I'm missing despite exhausting all obvious solutions I could think of.

session info is as follows:

```
R version 3.3.2 (2016-10-31)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 7 x64 (build 7601) Service Pack 1
```

locale:

```
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_United States.1252  LC_CTYPE=English_United States.1252   
[3] LC_MONETARY=English_United States.1252 LC_NUMERIC=C                          
[5] LC_TIME=English_United States.1252
```

attached base packages:

```
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base
```

other attached packages:

```
[1] RODBC_1.3-14         stringr_1.1.0        RMySQL_0.10.9        DBI_0.5-1            dplyr_0.5.0         
 [6] tidyr_0.6.0          httr_1.2.1           readxl_0.1.1         data.table_1.9.6     dtplyr_0.0.1        
[11] RevoUtilsMath_10.0.0 RevoUtils_10.0.2     RevoMods_10.0.0      MicrosoftML_1.0.0    mrsdeploy_1.0       
[16] RevoScaleR_9.0.1     lattice_0.20-34      rpart_4.1-10
```

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):

> Error in x[["Version"]] : subscript out of bounds
>   In addition: Warning message:
>   In FUN(X[[i]], ...) :
>     DESCRIPTION file of package 'jsonlite' is missing or broken

odbc error I'm getting:

> Error in loadNamespace(name) : there is no package called ‘odbc’

jsonlite I get, before "installing.package":

Loading required package: jsonlite

> Warning message:
>   In library(package, lib.loc = lib.loc, character.only = TRUE, logical.return = TRUE,  :
>     there is no package called ‘jsonlite’

Comment: What message are you seeing that makes you think they "need an install"? What is your `sessionInfo()` (that should show RStudio and R version numbers)? Your question doesn't have many specifics to really help get to the bottom of what's going on.

Comment: Were you by chance using [`packrat`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/packrat/index.html) or [`checkpoint`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/checkpoint/index.html) for package version reproducibility? If yes and you've recently changed your working directly, that can affect package visibility.

Comment: What version of R were you using previously? [`odbc`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/odbc/index.html) is only dependent on R >= 3.2.0, so unless you *really* jumped recently, the only think I can think of is you have regressed inadvertently from R-3.4, and the compiled DLLs are too new for R-3.3 ...

Comment: Also, go to *Tools > Global Options > General* and see where it thinks R is located. Go to that directory and look around (above it) to see if there is a different version of R available. If so, change that value to the other version's directory and see if that remedies things.

Answer (score 0):

In the end turns out my actual R install was in a directory that wasn't local (had no idea that was the case), and that directory was unavailable, so it reverted to the previous version of R I had installed, which wasn't compatible with much of what I was trying to do.

Thanks for the help, poor practice on my part.